# What geom is used to get sample size 'tick' marks at the bottom of plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gratia

I've been using the `draw` function in the R package `gratia` to take a preliminary look at model results. This function puts 'tick' marks along the x axis to show where there are samples. What geom in ggplot is used to do this?

```
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100, 10, 1),
                 x = seq(1, 100, 1))
m <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = df)
draw(m)
```

[image]

Comment: That's a "rug plot", and `geom_rug()` draws them.

Comment: See for example the use of `geom_rug()` in [this source code](https://github.com/gavinsimpson/gratia/blob/6a1135dc577709d0e6996be885c9a071cbfc96b6/R/draw-methods.R) for `gratia::draw-methods.R`. The `draw()` function has a `rug = ` argument which is TRUE by default - [documentation](https://gavinsimpson.github.io/gratia/reference/draw.gam.html).

Comment: Thanks both! @user2554330 do you want to put this in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: No, feel free to do it yourself though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @user2554330, this can be replicated with geom_rug.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100, 10, 1),
                 x = seq(1, 100, 1))
m <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = df)
draw(m)
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = y), method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "tp")) +
  geom_rug(aes(x = x))
```